# Python: how to insert gaps of silence to generated .wav file?

Tags: python, audio

I'm writing a simple script that generates random "glitches" out of a source audio file.  It reads a random chunk of a source audio file and writes that chunk to a new .wav file, followed by a gap of silence, followed by a different chunk, then silence, etc .

I tried reading about the .wav format to understand what "silence" is, but most of it is over my head.  Silence simply seems to be a (hex?) value of 0, it seems.  I made a pure silence file for analysis, and in notepad the silence was represented as spaces, whereas in sublime text it was a bunch of 0s.  So my approach was to take the silence character (either a " " or a 0), multiply it by how many characters a frame is for the source audio (so it automatically corrects for different possible .wav attributes, mono stereo etc), and then multiply that by how many frames of silence one wants for the gap.   Everything works fine except that whatever I'm writing as the silence is inevitably written at some value that, though consistent, does have amplitude and therefore shows up like this in the wave:

[image: Waveform]

and in a hex editor the gap is always some repeating pattern like 30303030303030 or something.  I'm obviously doing something wrong or misunderstanding the nature of .wav data,   but I can't figure it out.  Here is a basic stripped-down version of the code:

```
import sys
import wave

script, filename = sys.argv

sourceFile = wave.open(filename, 'r')
sampleParams = sourceFile.getparams()

def randChunk(source):
    blahblah
    # Returns random chunk of audio from sourceFile


numGlitch = int(raw_input('How many glitches do you want?: '))
silenceSpace = int(raw_input('How many frames of silence between glitches?: '))

singleglitchFile = filename[:-4] + '_glitch.wav'
outfile = wave.open(singleglitchFile, 'w')
# set the outfile params to whatever sourceFile params were
outfile.setparams(sampleParams)

# WHERE EVERYTHING GOES WRONG 
silence = 0 # or " " or hex(0) or whatever the hell silence is supposed to be
frameLength = len(sourceFile.readframes(1))
emptyspace = (silence * frameLength) * silenceSpace

for n in range(numGlitch):
    outfile.writeframes(randChunk(sourceFile))
    outfile.writeframes(emptyspace)

outfile.close()
```

Figuring out a solution not only would get this script working but would help me figure out the next phase: how to get the average amplitude of sequential frames in the source and filter out any that dont meet a certain threshold (i.e. filter out chunks that are too quiet).

Answer (score 3):

The character with the value 0 is `chr(0)` or `'\x00'`. `0` is an integer, so multiplying it gives you the result of integer multiplication. `0 * anything` is `0` but `'\x00' * 3` is `'\x00\x00\x00'`.

Comment: Exactly this. Do `ord("0")` to see for yourself -- "0" as a string is ordinal 48, which is what's causing the constant amplitude in your wave.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So I tried changing silence to '\x00' and the output still makes those damn rectangles!  What am I missing here?